# Django error: Field 'id' expected a number but got '{}'

Tags: python, django

I'm coding a book store and on the single product page above the title of the book, I have a link that directs the customer to the author profile page. The link is showing fine but when I click on it I get this error:

```
ValueError at /book_details/{}
Field 'id' expected a number but got '{}'.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/book_details/%7B%7D
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Field 'id' expected a number but got '{}'.
Exception Location: /Users/ariethan/Documents/django_apps/ibdb/virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py, line 1824, in get_prep_value
Python Executable:  /Users/ariethan/Documents/django_apps/ibdb/virt/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.9
Python Path:    
['/Users/ariethan/Documents/django_apps/ibdb/ibdb',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
 '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/ariethan/Documents/django_apps/ibdb/virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 13 Jan 2022 09:43:37 +0000

/Users/ariethan/Documents/django_apps/ibdb/ibdb/ibdb_app/views.py, line 53, in book_details
    book_details = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
```

urls.py

```
path('author_details/<ath_id>',views.author_details,name='author_details'),
```

view.py

```
def author_details(request,ath_id):
    author_details = BookAuthor.objects.get(pk=ath_id)
    return render(request,'author_details.html',{
            'author_details':author_details,
        })
```

html

```
 <a href="{% url 'author_details' ath.id %}">{{book_details.book_author}}</a>
```

Comment: could you share your views ?

Comment: def author_details(request,ath_id):
 author_details = BookAuthor.objects.get(pk=ath_id)
 return render(request,'author_details.html',{
   'author_details':author_details,
  })





def index(request):
 return render(request,'index.html',{

  })



def book_details(request,book_id):
 book_details = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
 return render(request,'book_details.html',{
   'book_details':book_details
  })

Comment: its not letting me--it says theres too much code

Comment: i get this error | Reverse for 'author_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['author_details/(?P<ath_id>[^/]+)\\Z']

Comment: def author_details(request,ath_id):
 author_details = BookAuthor.objects.get(pk=ath_id)
 return render(request,'author_details.html',{
   'author_details':author_details,
  })

Answer (score 0):

hi because you pass a ***{}*** to your URL /book_details/***{}*** and in your view try to get a integer id like : /book_details/***12***

if read carefully errors you can find mistakes

```
ValueError at /book_details/{}
Field 'id' expected a number but got '{}'.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/book_details/%7B%7D
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your html code to

`<a href="{% url 'author_details' author_details.id %}">{{book_details.book_author}}</a>`
because you have not passed `ath` to the template as context

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be helpful:

```py
def author_details(request,ath_id):
    author_details = BookAuthor.objects.get(ath_id=author_details)
    return render(request,'author_details.html',{
            'author_details':author_details,
        })
```